# Adding subdomain to home_url for "add_menu_page"

Tags: php, plugin-development, site-url, add-menu-page, home-url

I am trying to add a Wordpress admin menu item that will point to a URL which is

`http://docs.[currentdomain]`

My plugin code is currently:

```
function user_manual() {
    add_menu_page(
        __( 'Custom Menu Title', 'textdomain' ),
        'Manual',
        'manage_options',
        'http://docs' . home_url(),
        '',
        'dashicons-book-alt',
        1
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'user_manual' );
```

But what I end up with is currently: `http://docshttp/www.domain.com`

How can I achieve this without hardcoding the domain name in?

Answer (score 1):

The way of your approach is arguably wrong. One shouldn't use `add_menu_page` for external links as that function isn't created for that purpose. Add menu page adds a page in the admin area with `menu_slug` as the fourth argument.

If we take a look at [`add_menu_page`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L1077)/[`dev ref`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) source, we can notice that whatever the URL we pass in the function is passed through [`plugin_basename`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_basename/) / [`dev ref`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/plugin.php#L728) which normalizes and replaces the path giving us the path relative to plugin directory.

---

Instead you can hook it to admin bar which in my opinio correct place to put external link(if this is only purpose)

```
function wpse243214_user_manual($wp_admin_bar) {
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        //'parent'    => 'wpse-parent-id', // parent if any
        'id'        => 'wpse243214_usermanual',
        'title'     => __('User Manual'),
        'href'      => 'http://docs.'.basename(esc_url(home_url())),
    ) );
}
//change priority(15) accordingly
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wpse243214_user_manual', 15 );
```

With this we get

[image: WP Admin Bar]

Also note that I used `basename` for `home_url` otherwise we get a link with http or https scheme (`http://www.example.com`).

Comment: That works nicely however there's two issues: 1. If the visitor happens to be visiting "WWW.domain.com", the link ends up as "docs.www.domain.com" 2. I really did prefer it in the sidebar, below "Dashboard" with the icon because I need to be sure it's as prominent and high visibility as possible.